# Unable to click Submit Button_Web Scraping VBA

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba

I would require help in completing the coding for web scraping.

In the below given vba code am able to enter the username and password into the input boxes but not able to click the submit button to move further.

```
IE.navigate "http://wasbprbvl.corp.anheuser-busch.com/WMSBrwy/Login"
            Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            Loop
        IE.document.forms("Login").elements("j_username").Value = "UserName"
        IE.document.forms("Login").elements("j_password").Value = "XXXXXXX"

        Set tagNames = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")
        i = 0
        While i < tagNames.Length
            If tagNames(i).Type = "submit" And tagNames(i).Value = "Submit" Then
                Set objElement = tagNames(i)
                GoTo clickCode
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Wend
```

clickCode:
            objElement.Click
        End If

I have also attached the screenshot of page along with the inspect screen.

[image]

Regards,
Raj

Comment: But you get an error?

Comment: Try submitting the form instead. E.g. something like this`ie.document.getElementsByTagName("form")(0).submit`

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is going to be more challenging to deal with, compared to regular old HTML, but anyway, it looks like the button is named 'Submit'.  Did you try to  click 'Submit'?

```
IE.Document.getElementById("UserID").Value = "something" 'Login
IE.Document.getElementById("Password").Value = "something" 'Password
IE.Document.getElementById("Submit").Click 'Submit button
```